# What does this Python code do: shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))

Tags: python, macos, command-line

I don't understand what this code is doing, 
I'm wanting to run a command line, in Mac OS X, the code I'm using is from somebody running a  Windows command line.  The command still executes, but I'd like to know what the sys.platform!="win32" is for, and if I should change it to something else for Mac OS X.  It seems to be saying sys.platform is not Win32, but that doesn't seem to me.

```
return_code = subprocess.call(str(cline), shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what this code does and does not:

- It doesn't compile (syntax error -
  you need a comma between the
  arguments) , - not anymore.
- It starts a subprocess
  and, if you are not on win32 it
  starts it through the shell. The
  "shell" argument can be True or
  False and `sys.platform != 'win32'` can also evaluate to either True or False.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the comma.  I took it out by accident when trying to format it for the question.

Answer (score 3):

Same as :

```
if sys.platform!="win32":
    return_code = subprocess.call(str(cline), shell=True)
else
    return_code = subprocess.call(str(cline), shell=False)
```

see [subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) (execute `cline`)